# How Get Unique meta title (post number), when Post Title already exist

Tags: wordpress, get, unique, title, permalinks

As i know, WordPress automatically adds suffix in the end of permalink (post name) if a post with the same name already exists in the database.

But not adds suffix in the end of Meta title, because its depend on themes.

Anyway im using Thesis Themes, no duplicate meta title for archive meta title,

**HOEMPAGE**

mydomainname.com = in page 1, the title is `<title>My Homepage Title</title>`

mydomainname.com/page/**2** = in page 2, the title is `<title>My Homepage Title — Page 2</title>`

**CATEGORY**

mydomainname.com/category/category-title = in page 1, the title is `<title>My Category Title</title>`

mydomainname.com/category/category-title/page/**2** = in page 2, the title is `<title>My Category Title — Page 2</title>`

**TAGS**
Its same, always unique dynamically.

More and more page 3,4,5++ title still unique (not duplicate) AUTOMATICALLY.

Im using Thesis Themes on my blog (Public user can update post on Fropnt End), user only create post on Front End, Authors can't access my wp-admin CMS and Thesis "Details and Additional Style" fields. So, How about Post Entry Title? How to get this features when user Create New Post with the same Title?

**Example, im trying to do like below:**

[webresepi.com/sambal-udang](http://webresepi.com/sambal-udang) = first post meta title is `<title>Sambal Udang</title>`

[webresepi.com/sambal-udang-**2**](http://webresepi.com/sambal-udang-2/) = this post title already exist on my database, so i want this post meta title like this `<title>Sambal Udang — 2</title>`

get number from that permalink when Post Title is already exist on database.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Is it for say articles that span multiple pages?

Comment: Hi Calle, im only trying to add that post number (number on permalink) to my post Meta Title (when Post Title is already exist). 

The purpose is, avoid duplicate title in Google / Bing / TC SERP. So, while Post Title already exist, but in SERP title its still unique (not duplicate).

Any idea? Thanks so much Calle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This uses the same idea as faa, but his solution has lots and lots of things in it that will prevent it from working. Use FTP to find your theme in the folder /wp-content/themes/ and then put this piece of code in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
if( is_single() ) { // Is a single post
    $slug = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // The slug e.g. sambal-udang-2
    $slug = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $slug ) );
    add_filter( 'wp_title', function( $title ) use( $slug ) {
        return $slug;
    }); // This filter overrides wp_title which is used to print the meta title. It replaces whatever would we written normally with our edited version of the slug.
}
});
```

The above piece of code assumes your server uses PHP version 5.3 or later. For support on older systems, we need to do away with anonymous functions:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'xyz_tmplt_redirect' );

function xyz_tmplt_redirect() {
    if( is_single() ) {
        add_filter( 'wp_title', 'xyz_change_title' );
    }
}

function xyz_change_title( $title ) {
    $slug = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // The slug e.g. sambal-udang-2
    $slug = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $slug ) );
    return $slug;
}
```

Comment: Hi Calle, thanks your advance...

But after i paste this code on my thesis_185/custom/custom_functions.php file, i get eror when login.. Any idea? thanks Calle, appreciate it.

Comment: What is the error? If it doesn't show, you could open wp-config.php and change WP_DEBUG to true temporarily. It will then show you the error. I tried changing something in the code that I think might be the problem, try the new version out too.

Comment: Also, let me say that I am not familiar with Thesis. The functions.php I'm referring to I think would be thesis_185/functions.php. It is possible that Thesis attaches its own filters to wp_title, which could screw things up.

Comment: Hi Calle, after paste this code on my function.php its appear like this (http://www.diigo.com/item/image/1p4yt/nbga?size=o) . Anyway, if you want to see my php code on custom_function.php, you can see here >> http://pastie.org/5736278 .

Comment: Looks like your server has an old version of PHP on it. Only PHP version 5.3 and later supports anonymous functions. I tried to rewrite my code to be supported without it, so try that piece of code instead.

Comment: No, don't wait, try the code I posted already. The second one IS the one a rewrote.

Comment: Hi Celle, I have paste you new php code. But result is blank <title></title> on all Post Entry. Thanks Celle

Comment: Doing debugging this way is not optimal but haven't time to set things up on my server. Well, we know now that the filter works. It modifies the title. But $slug also ends up being empty, so that must mean $_SERVER['REQUEST_URL'] wasn't working. Now we're trying $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] instead. I updated the code with that.

Comment: Anyway, with this php code, how to adding more word between Post Title and Slug? e.g Sambal Udang Version 2

Comment: It's just very basic PHP. You should learn about it. Instead of str_replace, use explode and then concatenate the parts together however you want. At the end, use ucwords to capitalize the first letter in every word.